# Event listeners are not working in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

this is part of my code (where event listeners are added to my images).

```
var overlay = this.overlay;
    var icon_holder = this.icon_hld;
    var docfrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var images = holder.querySelectorAll('img');
    var that = this;
    function video_play() {
        console.log(this);
        this.style.display = 'none';
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.JGalleryMedia').style.display = '';
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.JGalleryMedia').play();
        this.parentNode.querySelector('.JGalleryMedia').autoplay = true;
    }
    [].forEach.call(images, function (img) {
        img.addEventListener('click', JGallery.prototype.showMe.bind(that), false);
    }
}
```

this is working nicly in opera and chrome, but not working in IE and FF.
I've seen caniuse.com, but I have not found anything I should not use in my code. If you want to see the working demo open zaervax.ir with chrome or opera and go to gallery and click on image thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok IE problem was about forEach (without .call)(I had this in several lines above the mentioned lines). and FF (v47) seems to has problems with forEach. I have updated my FF (to v50)(problem solved without code changing). And I decided not to use forEach ever again, and I used while instead. like so...

```
 var i = 0;
 while(i < images.length){
    var img = images.item(i);
    img.addEventListener('click', JGallery.prototype.showMe.bind(that), false);
}
```

and now it's working nicely, you can check it out in [zaervax.ir](http://www.zaervax.ir)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think you cannot pass parameters like this in the eventListener.

You could try an anonymous function like this:

```
img.addEventListener('click', function(){
    JGallery.prototype.showMe.bind(that)
}, false);
```

Also if you want to pass **this** as a parameters you can use the ES6 Arrow functions, so that you will be able to access **this** in your showMe() function. It is done like that:

```
img.addEventListener('click', event => this.JGallery.prototype.showMe(event), false);
```

[More infos about arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

If this is not working, can you try to open your console and tell us if there is any error message?